# jQuery - Animating textarea box height - Performance Issue

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-animate, textarea

Please keep in mind I'm still in the early learning stage of jQuery.

Having animation performance issue with the code below. It doesn't show performance issues in jsfiddle but on the website I'm constructing the .js file and html file is huge!

The purpose of the code is to animate a textarea height on focus and blur the box to the original height.

I thought combining the functions might increase performance but the opposite happened.

```
$("#productsServiceDescription, #targetAudienceDescription").focus(function() {

    $(this).animate({
        height: 100
    }, "normal"),

    $(this).blur(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            height: 51
        }, "normal")
    });
});​
```

Code Here

http://jsfiddle.net/clearpixelsolutions/Yn477/

Here's the code with functions separated, performance is so so on the animation, but combined like shown above its awful.

```
$("#productsServiceDescription, #targetAudienceDescription").focus(function() {

    $(this).animate({
        height: 100
    }, "normal"),
});
$("#productsServiceDescription, #targetAudienceDescription").blur(function() {

    $(this).animate({
        height: 51
    }, "normal")
});​
```

I was wanting to combine the functions to eliminate reproducing the id tags. I will have a total of 15 ids or so using this function.

I'm hoping someone might tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to optimize the code.

Comment: Try animating with CSS3, it'll be much smoother and you keep your JS neat and clean.

Comment: I tried CSS3 and yes it was smooth but in IE the animation is broken/not supported so this is why I was looking at doing it via js. I might resort to going back to CSS and just live with it being broken in IE. By the way, was the jsfiddle active? As for forming clean readable code I do need some work on that, among other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using class will be better solution, like

```
$(".one_full_a3 textarea").focus(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        height: 100
    }, "normal");
}).blur(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        height: 51
    }, "normal");
});​
```

[See the updated demo​](http://jsfiddle.net/thujeevan/Yn477/3/)

Comment: @RichardMax  think i couldn't get your question, let me know what you actually expect?

Comment: I just noticed you changed more than just the Id to a Class...I see you shifted the $(this) It did eliminate the performance issue. Thanks a million 'so geek' To be compatible with all browsers do you think this is the way to go?

Comment: After thinking about it guess I could use CSS and the jQuery as a fall back for IE. If you could help with the jQuery fall back that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @RichardMax Sure, take a look http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html for css cross browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at http://jquerypp.com/? 
This jQuery plugin extends the animate function of jQuery for CSS3 support on supported browsers. Just embed the script just the line after embedding jQuery and relax, viewing the smooth animations :)

Comment: Very interesting... Will take a look and see how useful this could be for me in the future. Thanks!